# Linq to Entities, ViewModel - DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a db table with a `start date` DateTime field (SQL Server). In my repository I have a "get all" method that returns all the columns. I also have a viewmodel with a `DateTime Startdate` field.

Repository property:

```
    public IQueryable<Module> LeadershipModules
    {
        get
        {
            return from module in context.Modules where module.ModuleTypeId == 2 select module;
        }
    }
```

In my controller, how do I set the `StartDate` field to a `DateTime` object?

My controller

```
    public ActionResult Leadership()
    {
        var viewModel = new LeadershipModulesViewModel
        {
            LeadershipModules = repository.LeadershipModules,
            StartDate = **???**

        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

When I tried the following:

`StartDate = from startDate in repository.LeadershipModules where startDate.StartDate > DateTime.Now select startDate`

I get the error below error message

`Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Domain.Module>' to 'System.DateTime' Controllers\ModuleController.cs 41  117 WebUI`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You view contains multiple modules but a single start date. What will be the value of start date exactly?

Comment: I wanted to get all the modules that are after a certain date.Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Leadership()
{
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
    var modules = repository.LeadershipModules.Where(m => m.StartDate > startDate);

    var viewModel = new LeadershipModulesViewModel
    {
        LeadershipModules = modules,
        StartDate = startDate
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the `Single()`, or `First()` extension methods. Example:

```
StartDate = (
    from module in repository.LeadershipModules
    where module.StartDate > DateTime.Now 
    select module.StartDate)
    .First();
```

The query you defined is an `IQueryable<Module>` which is basically a collection of `Module` objects. C# cannot implicitly cast this to a DateTime. You you will have to do the proper mapping, which means select the StartDate object, not the module. And execute the query and get a single item of the list (the first, the last, the only, the max, the min, etc).

Comment: Thank you but I am trying to get all the modules that are greater than today's date.